# Wallet as authenticator with WalletConnect

Tags: external-api, authentication, walletconnect

I want to use the wallet in my web app as authenticator for an API access, e.g. by signing an arbitrary string and then check the signature at the API side. I know there are sign() methods to do so. However, is there a possibility to get a sign at connect() time, so that the user does not need to confirm twice, once for the connect, once for the sign()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a possibility to get a sign at connect() time, so that the user does not need to confirm twice, once for the connect, once for the sign()?

Unfortunately, the wallet interaction is limited to APIs available. I am pretty sure the connection can be cached, though, and WalletConnect does not need to reconnect every time. This depends on a wallet and the support may vary.